# KineticJS won't draw multiple images

Tags: kineticjs

I am trying to draw multiple images on canvas using for loop.
For some reason it only displays image on last position.

```
<script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.2.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<script defer="defer">    
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 200
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

// add the layer to the stage
stage.add(layer);

for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function() { 
        var yoda = new Kinetic.Image({

            x: 100*i,
            y: 50,
            image: this,
            width: 106,
            height: 118
        });

        // add the shape to the layer
        layer.add(yoda);
        stage.draw();

    };
    imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg';
}
</script>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3eKn/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you're reusing `var imageObj` inside a loop.

Before the first image has been loaded, imageObj is being overwritten in the next step through the loop.

So fully load `imageObj` outside the loop and add multiple `yoda`s inside the loop like this:

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/uK4DW/

```
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
    for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
        var yoda = new Kinetic.Image({
            x: 100*i,
            y: 50,
            image:imageObj,
            width: 106,
            height: 118
        });
        layer.add(yoda);
        layer.draw();
    };
}
imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg';
```

Comment: Hi @markE , what if I want to load different images (different src)?

Comment: @Elsa, every programmer should have a multiple-image-preloader in their toolkit. Here's the one I use but there are many out there:  https://gist.github.com/m1erickson/1dbeeae071e986ddc45c  So browse a little and then add one to your toolkit! Cheers!